# The exchange potential in Kohn-Sham equations for harmonic interactions

Tags: computational-physics, many-body, density-functional-theory

Is there an analytic formula for the exchange potential part in the effective potential of the [Kohn-Sham equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohn%E2%80%93Sham_equations) for a system of N  Bosons in a harmonic trap with mutual harmonic interactions  or a simple prescription to compute it numerically?

Comment: 3 years is long for no answer, why not copy and paste into https://materials.stackexchange.com?